# Save properties of a Webpart programmatically

Tags: web-part, properties

I want to save the properties of web part somewhere in Xml/Xslt, So that if i remove a web part and then, again add it.
previous properties will be retrieved automatically into the web part.

Comment: For a custom webpart or for all webparts (custom as well as out-of-the-box webparts)?

Comment: Custom and out of the box webpart

Answer (score 0):

For custom web parts it is pretty easy. You have to override the `OnPreRender` event and then read or write an XML document (standard c#, no magic).

For out-of-the-box web parts it is a really difficult as there doesn't exist functionality in the SSOM which supports this universally.
To do this with out-of-the-box web parts you'd have to do 1 of 2 things:

1. If you are on a SharePoint Enterprise, you'd have to create custom pagelayouts which has a codebehind that loops through all web parts present in the `WebPartManager`.
2. Create a UserControl which gets loaded onto every page by a delegate control, which then loops through all web parts present in the `Page` object.

Besides the 2 points above, you'd have to make a class which not only reads all properties from an XML file, but also creates and populates all properties to a XML file. Keep in mind though that you will need to have some way to identify every individual web part. Saving properties for just a `ContentEditorWebPart` is not good enough as you can have multiple of those one a single page and each can have their own settings.

I am tempted to say that doing this for out-of-the-box web parts is impossible.